# How to use a URL list (.txt) in python correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests-html

I need to make a checker for availability of an unlimited number of sites, could you please tell me how to implement a list of URLs so the script reads the URLs from the .txt and loops each of them?

My approximate non-working code:

```
import requests
urls_list = open('G:\\urls_list.txt', 'r+')
for url in urls_list:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('Not active'.format(url))
```

Comment: what is your expectation and what is not working?

Comment: I want the code to check each URL from the list (.txt) and if the site is not working, it will display the wrong URL
In my code, for some reason, URLs are not read, and if I put a couple of non-working sites there, then the code generally gives an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because, when doing `for url in urls_list: ...`, the `url` string will contain a newline character `\n` at the end.

You need to use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove them.

Also, you better use a context-manager when reading files (`with open("urls.txt") as f`), it handles closing the file for you.

```py
import requests

with open("urls.txt") as f:
    for url in map(str.rstrip, f):

        print("-" * 34)
        print(f"{url = }")

        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
        except requests.ConnectionError as e:
            print(e)
            continue

        print(f"{response.status_code = }")
```

```
----------------------------------
url = 'https://github.com/'
response.status_code = 200
----------------------------------
url = 'https://githubb.com/'
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='githubb.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f26a6758f70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
----------------------------------
url = 'https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html'
response.status_code = 200
----------------------------------
url = 'https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashh.html'
response.status_code = 404
----------------------------------
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
response.status_code = 200
----------------------------------
url = 'https://stackoverfloww.com/'
response.status_code = 200
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you really helped a lot.
And can you please advise how, or with which module (library) can i configure the intervals between inspections teh sites?

Comment: You're welcome. What do you call "the intervals"?

Comment: time intervals, i.e. set a certain time between each site check

Comment: [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/time.html#time.sleep)?